# How can I start to solve a word chain in haskell?

Tags: haskell, cpu-word, chain

> Let us know if the word chain game was played correctly! The object of the game is to form another word with the last letter of the previous word. The words are separated by a space. The words function can help you solve this problem.

```
Each of the following test cases must give a True:

validGame "apple table lo shoulder dog" == True
validGame "converse veg ball tablecloth zsifaf fules" == True
validGame "forest divide west tabortuz" == False
validGame "sobbing guzsalyas sararany nyul leng" == False
```

Comment: What did you try? What is not working?

Comment: ```validGame :: String -> Bool
validGame (x:y:xs)
 | x==y = validGame xs 
 | y== validGame xs = True
 |otherwise= False```

Comment: I don't know how can I check the starting Char and the ending Char.

Comment: use `head` and `last`

Comment: @hello16: the first character of a list (string) `x` can be determined with `head x`, and the last one with `last x`.

Comment: also, hows 'validGame "converse veg ball tablecloth zsifaf fules" == True` valid? `tablecloth` has `h` as its last char and `zsifaf` doesn't use `h`.

Comment: @user1984: the first one also does not make much sense, since the last character of `table` is not used in `lo`. The last one on the other hand is `False`, but that is one where each last letter is used in the next word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```hs
validGame :: String -> Bool
validGame (x:' ':z:xs) = (x==z) && validGame (z:xs)
validGame (x:xs) = validGame xs
validGame [] = True
```

Comment: Hehe. That's going to report wrong if there's any single-letter words. "I imagine".

Comment: validGame (x:' ':z:xs) = (x==z) && validGame xs ... validGame (x:' ':z:xs) = (x==z) && validGame z:xs